# How to stop a timer when debugging?

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem when trying to debug my code, my code is running a timer which invokes an event every 16 milliseconds, when I enter debug mode the timer continue to call the events and causing the debugger to behave weird.

I would like to have my code stop when I'm in debug mode.

Thats the timer code:

```
        private System.Timers.Timer CreateTimer()
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer
            {
                Interval = 16
            };
            timer.Elapsed += MainTick;
            return timer;
        }
        
        private void MainTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var shape in Shapes)
            {
                Calc(shape);
                CalcStuff(shape);
                CalcSomeMoreStuff(shape);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The obvious answer is to use the debugger.

Comment: This is off topic, but surely `Timer` isn't accurate enough to guarantee 16ms intervals.  You'd be better off spawning a main thread and doing the timing in that

Comment: If you have "unexpected behavior" now then you'll have a disappointing outcome when you don't debug.  Timer has no execution guarantee, this *will* go wrong.  You'll much prefer this reliably going wrong rather than occasionally going wrong to get this code stable.

Comment: Also note, System.Timers.Timer raises Elapsed on the ThreadPool (unless you set SynchronizationObject).

Comment: @itsme86 not sure what do you mean, maybe you got my question wrong, the unexpected behavior occurs when I enter debug mode.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the advice! what do you mean by spawning the main thread?

Comment: @HansPassant I'm debbuging.. but when I'm entering debug mode the debugger have unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Lloyd Thanks I will note that, Thanks!

Comment: By the way, not sure why anyone downvote this, if he could tell me why it would be great.

Comment: @AmitKahlon What I mean is that often in applications like this (i.e. games), a loop runs in its own thread that co-ordinates timed actions such as these

Comment: edited the title and body, does this bring more focus on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem with event driven architecture. Microsoft created an entire library/framework to deal with this kind of problem.

> Install-Package System.Reactive

And

> Install-Package Microsoft.Reactive.Testing

You will find in `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing` the class `TestScheduler`. This is a class which you can inject into your domain code, and then drive the clock manually via an API programmatically.

When used in production, you simply inject a `IScheduler` based on the System Clock, such as WinFormScheduler (for WinForm), or DispatcherScheduler (for WPF).

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Debugger.IsAttached` (from `System.Diagnostics`) in your timer interval to determine whether the code is being debugged and change the behaviour as a result of it:

```
private void MainTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        foreach (var shape in Shapes)
        {
            Calc(shape);
            CalcStuff(shape);
            CalcSomeMoreStuff(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

The `IsAttached` property literally tells you whether a debugger is attached to the process:

> `Debugger.IsAttached` Gets a value that indicates whether a debugger
> is attached to the process.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Debugger_IsAttached

Comment: For some reason it always return true, I'm trying to figure it out at the moment, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @AmitKahlon It only returns true if you are looking. You need the Debugger Attached to look...>_<

Comment: @Aron It actually returns true when I have no debugger attached

Comment: @AmitKahlon How exactly are you "checking" that it returns true? It is the debugger that is helping you look at the value. Any time Visual Studio is interacting with the running code, it is using the Debugger. If you really want to check the status of `Debugger.IsAttached` log the value to console...

Comment: @Aron  I know it returns true because it doesnt reach the code inside the if